EM Wave Equation: Insufficient initial conditions for NDSolve?
I am trying to model a EM wave propagation through a region of free space. However, Mathematica tells that there are insufficient initial conditions, even though I specify all values at t==0 in ic equation below. How can this be resolved?

(*constants*)
mu0 = 1.26 10^-6;(*N A-2*)
eps0 = 8.85 10^-12; (*F m-1*)
f = 2.45 10^9; (*Hz*)

r = 0.15; (*m*)
disk = Disk[{0, 0}, r]; (*domain of simulation*)

eq = {
  Laplacian[e[t, x, y], {x, y}] + mu0 eps0 D[e[t, x, y], {t, 2}] == 0
  }

(*boundary conditions*)
bc = {DirichletCondition[e[t, x, y] == Sin[2 Pi f t], x <= -0.3 r]};
(*initial conditions*)
ic = {DirichletCondition[e[t, x, y] == 0, t == 0]}; 

sol = NDSolve[Flatten@{eq, bc, ic}, e, {t, 0, 10^-9}, {x, y} \[Element] disk]


Initial conditions are not specified as DirichletCondition. Try e[0,x,y]==0.

@user21 Didn't help, still the same error.

Well you also need to specify the derivative of the initial condition.

This time integrates:
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc, e[0, x, y] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][e][0, x, y] == 0}, 
  e, {t, 0, 10^-9}, {x, y} \[Element] disk]

